# Refreshing Radiobutton selection

Tags: python, tkinter, radio-button

I've created a quiz using tkinter and ive bumped into a small problem. After having chosen the answer for the first question and clicking submit, the same radiobutton is already selected from the previous question for the next question. Is there anyway of maybe refreshing the page so that there is no selected answer for the next question?

The image shows an answer being selected for the first question.

[image: The image shows an answer being selected for the first question.]

after having clicked submit, the same radio button choice is already selected.

[image: after having clicked submit, the same radio button choice is already selected.]

```
var =  IntVar()

ans1 = Radiobutton(root, text=answer1[count], variable=var, value=1,
                  command=sel)
ans2 = Radiobutton(root, text=answer2[count], variable=var, value=2,
                  command=sel)
ans3 = Radiobutton(root, text=answer3[count], variable=var, value=3,
                  command=sel)
ans4 = Radiobutton(root, text=answer4[count], variable=var, value=4,
                  command=sel)

ans1.pack()
ans2.pack()
ans3.pack()
ans4.pack()

def out():
    global QuestionNo,correct,incorrect,s,count
    global ans1, ans3, ans3 ,ans4, correctans
    # count = count + 1

    answer = (ans1 or ans2 or ans3 or ans4(var.get()))

    print (question[QuestionNo])


    # print (answer[count])
    if count != 3:
          if answer  == correctans :
              count = count + 1
              QuestionNo = QuestionNo + 1
              # entry.delete(0, END)
              correct = correct + 1
              label.config(text = question[QuestionNo])
          else:
              QuestionNo = QuestionNo + 1
              count = count + 1
              # entry.delete(0, END)
              incorrect = incorrect + 1
              label.config(text = question[QuestionNo])

          # answer.delete(0, END)
    elif count == 3:
        # entry.delete(0, END)
        label.config(text = "Correct: "+str(correct) + " Incorrect:   "+str(incorrect))

    ans1.configure(text=str(answer1[count]))
    ans2.configure(text=str(answer2[count]))
    ans3.configure(text=str(answer3[count]))
    ans4.configure(text=str(answer4[count]))  

button = tk.Button(root,text = "Submit",command = out)
button.pack()
```

Comment: use `var.set(0)`. BTW: you rather need `answer = var.get()`. If `answer1[count]` is text, then you don't have to use `str()`

Comment: BTW: to make code more readable put all your functions before `root = Tk()`

Comment: Thanks, that fixed it @furas

Comment: @furas Im unable to create another question and i was wondering if you could help me on another thing. When i run the quiz i seem to be getting a "list index out of range" error on the line "label.config(text = question[QuestionNo])". Any ideas why that might be?

Comment: check `QuestionNo` - Message `index out of range` means that you have (for example) 4 questions but you try to get 5th question. Remeber that if you have 4 question then its numbers are 0-3, not 1-4.

Comment: @furas I understand that and i only have 3 questions just for trial and error but i am unable to move on from the third question to the score calculator due to that error and im not sure what to do to fix it

Comment: if there is problem then always usefull is `print()` to see what values you have in variables - it helps find problem. First print `QuestionNo` and maybe `count`. Maybe you increase it in wrong place, maybe you should do it after `label.config(text = question[QuestionNo])`, not before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `var.set(0)` to reset selection.

Answer (score 0):

Did you use var for the radiobuttons in the different question pages?  You could use var1 for page 1 and var2 for page 2 to avoid carrying over.